# Portrait mode for Phones and Portrait+Landscape for Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait, portrait

I am building a universal android app, where phones need to support only portrait and tablets will support both portrait and landscape. Here is my layout structure

layout-port
layout-sw600dp-port
layout-sw600dp-land

But if the phone is in landscape mode, the app crashes, reasoning Resource not found Exception.

Comment: that because he has no resource in the default layout folder, and he not fall into  layout-sw600dp-land category

Comment: fine, but how shall I proceed now?

Comment: You want that phone will preview always portrait?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way should work:Define boolean value inside values-sw600dp boolean.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="tablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Define similar file inside the regular values folder and chnage the value to false:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="tablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Put this in your onCreate:

```
boolean tablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.tablet);
if (!tablet) 
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

Comment: I don't have these res/values-sw600dp and folder in my app. Can I add those folders?

Comment: Yes you can! you can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Thanks it helped so much

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can set your orientation programmatically in the activity like this

```
if(isTable()){
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}else{
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

where `isTablet()` method

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {

    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;

}// isTablet
```